# Passing a row data var from View Panel as property to a Custom Control

Tags: custom-controls, xpages

I have a `<xp:viewColumn>` in a Custom Control used for document locking purposes; I need to pass the row data var from my View Panel as Custom Property to my Custom Control.

I defined a new Property on Custom Control as:

> Name: rowEntry
>
> Type: com.ibm.xsp.model.ViewRowData

This is an example of my `ccColDocLocking` inside my View Panel; it works fine if I use same var on all my View Panels, but, I don't want to hard code it.

```
    <xp:viewPanel rows="15" id="viewPanel1" viewStyle="width:100%"
            rowClasses="even,odd" var="rowData">        
       <xp:this.data>
            <xp:dominoView viewName="IntakeForms" var="view1"></xp:dominoView>
       </xp:this.data>
       <xc:ccColDocLocking rowEntry="#{javascript:rowData}"></xc:ccColDocLocking>
       <xp:viewColumn columnName="reqDate" id="viewColumn1"
            displayAs="link" openDocAsReadonly="true">
            <xp:this.converter>
                <xp:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"></xp:convertDateTime>
            </xp:this.converter>
            <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Request  Date"
                id="viewColumnHeader1" sortable="true">
         </xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:viewColumn>
 </xp:view>
```

This is from my Custom Control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">    
    <xp:viewColumn id="viewColDocLock">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:viewColumnHeader xp:key="header" id="viewColumnHeader5">
            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:this.facets>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:""}]]></xp:this.value>
        <xp:image id="imgDocLock">
            <xp:this.url><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (rowData.getDocument().hasItem("$Writers") != "") {
    return "/locked.gif";
}}]]></xp:this.url>
            <xp:this.alt><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Document locked by " + @Name('[Abbreviate]', rowData.getDocument().getItemValueString("$Writers"))}]]></xp:this.alt>
            <xp:this.title><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Document locked by " + @Name('[Abbreviate]', rowData.getDocument().getItemValueString("$Writers"))}]]></xp:this.title>
        </xp:image>
    </xp:viewColumn>
</xp:view>
```

Error I'm getting is: [ReferenceError] 'compositeData' not found

when I try to replace `rowData.getDocument()` by `compositeData.rowEntry.getDocument()`

Comment: Please add this to your CustomControl: *<xp:br rendered="false" />*

Comment: If I add it before <xp:viewColumn>; it doesn't show at all. If I add it before <xp:image> and use something like compositeData.rowEntry.getDocument().getUniversalID(); it also shows [ReferenceError] 'compositeData' not found

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't show at all"? The *<xp:br>* tag is just a "dummy" component for your CC.

Comment: Yes, I see your point, however, this CC is just a column for my View Panel; starting with <xp:viewColumn>. Adding the <xp:br rendered="false" /> before <xp:viewColumn> doesn't show the column contained on CC. If added just before <xp:image> shows error described above.

Comment: Try this: instead of #{javascript:rowData} pass #{rowData} as parameter to your CC. Sometimes this solves problems with references to me.

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth; I tried with EL and got same result.

Answer (score 4):

If you're passing the datasource to a repeat as compositeData it needs to be available at page load. By default that doesn't happen, by default the framework of the repeat is created at page load, but the data-specific contents calculated at run-time. Proof of this is that you can't use ${datasourceName.fieldName} in a binding in a repeat, only #{datasourceName.fieldName}

To do what you want you need to set repeatControls="true" on the repeat. This tells it "at page load create the contents of the repeat using x rows from this collection". Then you can pass the datasource.

HOWEVER, because the rows and data are written at page load, partial refreshes won't change the contents. You can't use a pager or anything like that. You are restricted to the data that is written in the repeat at page load time.

If that won't work for you, you'll need to pass a string reference to the custom control such as the UNID and add a datasource in your custom control that retrieves the relevant datasource.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I'm not using a repeat control is just a simple View Panel control where I'm adding a Custom Control that contains a <xp:viewColumn>. Issue is with any custom property I try to pass to my CC. Hope this helps. I have two scenarios where this idea is usefull 1. A column that contains a image (link that deletes the current row) 2. Scenario explained in original question, a column that displays if the document is locked. In both scenarios I want to pass the row data as a Custom Property.

Comment: A ViewPanel is just a repeat control that has specific layout and datasource options restricted to make it easier to use out-of-the-box. My explanation is valid for repeat control, view panel and data table.If there's not a repeatControls property, you won't be able to pass the rowData to a custom control. You'll need to pass the NoteID and retrieve the datasource again in the Custom Control.

Comment: Tanks for the explanation. In regards of passing NoteID, is something I already tried; I added a new Custom Property to check if the problem is with the Data Type. I created docID as string Type. So I added CC as `<xc:ccColDocLockingNew docID="#{javascript:rowData.getDocument().getUniversalID();}"> </xc:ccColDocLockingNew>` Inside my CC I added a <xp:text> as `<xp:inputText id="inputText2" rendered="true" value="#{javascript:compositeData.docID}"> </xp:inputText>` and still get 'compositeData' not found

Answer (score 2):

I found this in the Lotus Notes and Domino Application Development wiki
 that might help you:

> In the custom control:
>
> ```
> <xp:this.beforePageLoad>
> <![CDATA[#{javascript:this.setAutoRemove(false);}]]>
> </xp:this.beforePageLoad>
> ```

Source/more explanation:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_compositeData_not_found

Comment: I tried with `<xp:this.beforePageLoad>
<![CDATA[#{javascript:this.setAutoRemove(false);}]]>
</xp:this.beforePageLoad>` and got same result as adding <xp:br> or <xp:text> tags at the top of my CC where I don't get any error, but, column is not displayed.

Comment: I also tried with 'Compute on Page Load' when I'm getting values from compositeData.rowEntry... and I got HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception

Comment: Try setting the type to *object*. Not sure if it helps, but I've had some issues with strong typing on custom properties.

Comment: Tanks @Tommy; that was one of my first attempts. I even added a new Custom Property to check if the problem is whith the Data Type. I created docID as string Type. So I added CC as `<xc:ccColDocLockingNew rowEntry="#{javascript:rowData;}"
   docID="#{javascript:rowData.getDocument().getUniversalID();}">
  </xc:ccColDocLockingNew>` Inside my CC I added a <xp:text> as `<xp:inputText id="inputText2" rendered="true"
   value="#{javascript:compositeData.docID}">
  </xp:inputText>` and still get 'compositeData' not found

Answer (score 0):

[image: [![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AASN1.jpg)

Use var Picker Editor for 'com.ibm.xsp.model.ViewRowData' custom Property type inside the Custom control. Set your custom property value in view panel. Please see screen shots fyr.